# Finding the pointer to a singleton postmortem in GDB (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, postmortem-debugging

I am doing a postmortem analysis of a crashed program. I am on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04, x86), the code is written in C++.  The Program is using some singletons that may contain valuable information. Is it possible to find the pointer to the instance of a singleton if it was created like this:

```
SingletonType& SingletonType::getInstance(){
    static SingletonType* instance = new SingletonType();
    return *instance;
}
```

And if its is possible, how is it done in GDB?

Comment: `p/x &SingletonType::getInstance()`?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately you cannot do this whitout a running process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run gdb with the core file, and run the command

```
disassemble  SingletonType::getInstance
```

On my test-program I found a `mov 0x<addr>, %eax` instruction near the end of the method. A `print *(*(SingletonType**) <0xaddr>)` should print the contents of your singleton structure.

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't `dissassemble SingletonType::getInstance` directly? For one thing, depending on the base address, `disassemble <address_from_objdump>` might not even do the correct thing.

Comment: You are right. The given procedure gives me what I want but it is absolutely possible to disassemble by using the name of the function and it is also more elegant :)

Comment: Good point sehe. I removed the objdump part and updated the dissassemble command in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`show modules`<sup>1</sup> should probably tell you the base addresses, and `instance`, being statically allocated, should be visible in some kind of `objdump`/`nm` report. Yeah hairy maths.

The alternative would be to disassemble `SingletonType::getInstance()` and see what effective address gets loaded in the initialization/return path.

---

<sup>1</sup> Mmm can't find the exact match I was remembering. `info sharedlibrary` would get you most info.

Answer (score 2):

this is what I do, while inside the core with gdb:

```
(gdb) info var instance
```

this will list all the addresses of all the singletons instances, among which you will find the one of SingletonType

```
0x86aa960 SingletonType::getInstance()::instance
```

Now that I have the address you can print the your instance' pointed memory:

```
(gdb) p *((SingletonType*)0x86aa960)
```